# Fetching data through Node-red Dashboard

Tags: javascript, dashboard, node-red

I am using node-red to fetch data through MQTT. I am having response something like in the picture..

[image: Node Red Debug Screen]

No i want to get data w.r.t Phase1,Phase2,Phase3,Phase4 and Timestamp separately with the help of functions.I dont know how to get like that way.
P.S I am new to node.red. Thankyou

Comment: All of those msgs have the same timestamp and topic -- were they split by a previous node?

Comment: I am sending all the msges on the same topic by publish.multiple in MQTT.. Is it a good idea to send the vlaues to separate topic using publish.single??

Comment: Since all of those readings are related to each other, and have a single event timestamp, it may make more sense to keep them together in a single payload. Ideally, you would publish a json structure that contains all 5 fields/values -- then your node-red flow would have the option to write  all the data to a new db record, do calculations across the 4 phases, or pull individual values out for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is get the numeric value out of each msg, you can use a `function` node to split the string, like so:

```
var parts = msg.payload.split(":");
var value = parts.length > 1 ? parts[1].trim() : parts[0].trim();

// append the string before the ":" to the topic...
msg.topic += "/" + parts.length > 1 ? parts[0] : "Total";
// coerce the value after the ":" to be numeric...
msg.payload = +value;
return msg;
```

Now you will have a topic and payload that you can show directly in your dashboard elements.

There are also at least 2 nodes that can do the same thing, without writing any javascript code. You might want to install and try the `node-red-contrib-string` node -- it is good for extracting bits of strings. The `change` node can also be used, but would require a Jsonata expression, which is powerful, but also a bit more complicated than even javascript code...